# Directive and data from API Service

Tags: angularjs

My service querys a database.

```
periodDataSvc.periodData = {};

periodDataSvc.refresh = function(user) {
    APIService.query({ route:'period', id: user._id }, function(data) {
        periodDataSvc.periodData.orders = data[0].orders;
        periodDataSvc.periodData.jobs = data[0].jobs;
        periodDataSvc.periodData.board = data[0].board;
        periodDataSvc.periodData.period = data[0].period;
        periodDataSvc.periodData.warehouse = data[0].warehouse;
        periodDataSvc.periodData.offers = data[0].offers;
    })
}
```

In my Controller I call the data:

```
$scope.periodData = PeriodDataService.periodData;
```

But in the moment my Template with the directive is loaded, the data isn't received from the controller, and the directive did not work (throws errors, for example from the filters).

`div(production-board="" period="periodData.period" data="periodData.board"`)

How can I promise, that the data ist loaded before the directive is rendered?

Thanks!

Comment: seems like you should fix the filters. Show more code

Answer (score 0):

You should use [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service. Init variable `periodData` with promise, resolve defered in your query result and in controller use:

```
PeriodDataService.periodData.then(function (data) { $scope.periodData = data; });
```

Edit 2:

```
var deferred = $q.defer()

periodDataSvc.periodData = deferred.promise;
periodDataSvc.refresh = function(user) {
    APIService.query({ route:'period', id: user._id }, function(data) {
       deferred.resolve(data[0]);
    })
}
```

Comment: but this didnt prevent the directive from loading data? can you show me please how to use $q in this context?

Comment: Thank you! but this did not prevent the directive from rendering without data

Comment: wrap you directive in container with directive ng-if='periodData'